# how to show the alert box when half of the time finished in online exam using javascript

Tags: javascript

i am doing online exam. I set the timer for exam using javascript. that is working perfect.i have little knowledge in javascript. i don't know how to show the alert box when the half of the test over. Please give the solution to me.

My code for timer:

```
function countDown() {
      sec--;
  if (sec == -01) {
    sec = 59;
    min = min - 1;
    if(min==-01)
        {
            min=59;
            hour=hour-1;
        }else
            {
                hour=hour;
            }
  } else {
   min = min;
  }
if (sec<=9) { sec = "0" + sec; }

  time = (hour<=9 ? "0" + hour : hour) + " : " + (min<=9 ? "0" + min : min) + " : " + sec + "";
if (document.getElementById) { document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = time; }
  SD=window.setTimeout("countDown();", 1000);
if (hour=='00'&& min == '00' && sec == '00') { sec = "00";min="00"; window.clearTimeout(SD); window.location=document.forms[0].action+"?fs=yes";}
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();`enter code here`
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should google a little before posting on SO.

Comment: http://bit.ly/11beSyV

Comment: alert('Message Goes Here');

Comment: You'll be more likely to get useful feedback if you show what code/approaches you've tried so far.

Comment: @tborychowski haha.  Nice one ;)

Comment: I wouldn't use the native alert. It might disrupt the users workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have total number of questions with you.
When the user answering each question u can increment a temp variable.
then check whether that temp equals to half of your total questions then u can give an alert.

like .
alert("Half of the test completed");